# Using custom config section with Enterprise Library Data Access

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, enterprise-library

How do I use the connectionString from an external configuration file in the Enterprise Library Data Access?

my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="custom.configuration.server" type="Custom.Framework.Core.Configuration.Server.CustomConfigurationServerSection, Custom.Framework.Core"/>
  </configSections>
  <custom.configuration.server configSource="custom.configuration.server.config"/>
</configuration>
```

my external config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<custom.configuration.server>
  <products>
    <add name="Product1">
      <enterprises>
        <add enterpriseKey="1" enterprise="Enterprise1">
          <databases>
            <add database="test" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=Enterprise1Test;Integrated Security=True" />
            <add database="development" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=Enterprise1Dvp;Integrated Security=True" />
          </databases>
        </add>
        <add enterpriseKey="2" enterprise="Enterprise2">
          <databases>
            <add database="test" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=Enterprise2Test;Integrated Security=True" />
            <add database="development" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=Enterprise2Dvp;Integrated Security=True" />
          </databases>
        </add>
      </enterprises>
    </add>
  </products>
</custom.configuration.server>
```

My sample call:

```
public void TestMethod1()
        {
            using (var customDatabase = new CustomDatabase("development"))
            {

            }
        }
```

Note: Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013, Net Framework 4.5, Enterprise Library 6.0, C#

*I found something that helped me in "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2006/04/02/entlib2externalconfig.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you put your external config file. I needed to put it on an environment where I could modify it. Here is a part of the code:

```
using System.Configuration;

public class ConfigHelper
{
    private const string ConfigPathString = @"{0}\MyApp\App.config";

    private string ConfigPath
    {
        get { return String.Format( ConfigPathString, System.Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData ) ); }
    }

    private Configuration Config
    {
        get
        {
            ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = ConfigPath;

            return ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration( fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None );
        }
    }

    public string ReadConString()
    {
        Configuration cfg = Config;
        return cfg.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[DefaultConnectionStringKey].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Comment: I mentioned external but in fact it is part of the same project. The difficulty is to use the "DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase (connectionStringName)" Enterprise Library because it does not recognize the name passed as a valid connectionString. The connectionString is that I used a custom class configuration via a string property, thank you!

Comment: So I misunderstood your question. But you can create a 'normal' app.config for each enterprise and/or product with specified names, like 'ent1.config' and use this code above. Otherwise I've no idea.

Comment: I need these unified settings to suit my project, anyway thanks for the help, I'll keep searching!